# Implementing PopupMenu using android.support.v7.appcompat

Tags: android

I want to implement PopupMenu like in google play app below is my code

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
    popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup);
    popup.show();
```

I have added appcompat7 to my application lib folder. below is the crash report when i click on button

```
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3607)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17477)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    ... 11 more
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.<clinit>(MenuPopupHelper.java:50)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.<init>(PopupMenu.java:69)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    at com.vs2.popupmenuexample.MainActivity.showPopup(MainActivity.java:26)
01-23 12:05:59.690: E/AndroidRuntime(14728):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try following solution :

Create a library project based on the support library code:

- Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the
  SDK Manager. Create a library project and ensure the required JAR
  files are included in the project's build path:
- Select File > Import.
- Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
- Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the appcompat project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
- Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.
- In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each
  .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example,
  when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the
  android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to
  the build path.
- Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path >
  Configure Build Path.
- In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to
  the build path, so they are   available to projects that depend on
  this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you
  to export both the android-support-v4.jar and
  android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
- Uncheck Android Dependencies.
- Click OK to complete the changes. You now have a library project for
  your selected Support Library that you can use with one or more
  application projects.

Add the library to your application project:

- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select
  Properties.
- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
- In the Library pane, click the Add button.
- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat
  project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
- In the properties window, click OK.

Source : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res